# Instantiating object with physics on Canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been trying to instantiate simple object on my canvas that would show added score value with some small visual and then fall down with gravity for a while before disappearing.
I Cant in any way make it visible  as UI element.
It is spawning at ridicolous position where canvas objects are physically. and even if i instantiate it as a child of my Ui element it has RectTransform but is not visible by camera as Ui element.
in my script "scoreValue" is ui element under which i'd want it to be instantiated,scoreVisualisationSpawnPoint is normal object with trasnform position i used earlier.
How to instantiate object on canvas at certain position in canvas for it to be visible?
Here is my not-working code:

```
 public void CreateAddScoreVisualisation(int addedScore)
{
    
    GameObject effect;

    effect =  Instantiate(addScoreVisialisation, scoreVisualisationSpawnPoint, scoreValue.transform.rotation,scoreValue.transform);

    effect.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = scoreValue.rectTransform.position;

    effect.GetComponent<ScoreVisualisation>().scoreText.text = addedScore.ToString();
    


}
```

Comment: I used something similar but done totaly different but might help you, I had popup text that would show a score value then drop and fade away, It was animated text that I would spawn in position with the correct value/color and the animation would take care of the rest

Comment: My problem is i cant make it spawn at desired position that would apropriatly change with camera size/position.

Comment: Okay, you need to parent it to the canvas `effect.transform.SetParent(canvas.trasnform, true)` with a second booleon value of true (it's `worldPositionStays`), You may need to rescale the effect afterwards.

Comment: eeven when im literaly adding a sprite into my Canvas , as its child -  the way i usualy add objects to scene and make it hudge its just not showing in my screen for some reason.  it is within Canvas it has rect, but its jsut not shown,

Comment: Check the Image alpha

Comment: I think i figured out what was the root problem of it all, i have to add it as Ui image for it to be displayed, which i did not know.

Answer (score 0):

That can be tricky at times, but are you sure this is the right approach at all?
I'd suggest have your object permanently there so you can set it up as you wish with the inspector and then in the start function, call `gameObject.SetActive(false)` to disable it.
Then instead of instantiating, activate it.
This will also be more performant by the way because small, inactive objects don't cost much but instantiating and destroying is relatively expensive.

Comment: It needs to be multiple copies and sometimes alot, im not attatched to any method of doing it, but the one is probably not so great, if anything i'd have to pool items, but im not concerned about performance anyways as its small game mostly for my educational purpose.